# Unable to acces Drop Down List using XPATH

Tags: selenium, webautomation

I am new in selenium Web automation. I am trying to access the elements in a drop down menu but unable to do so. Below is the HTML part:

```html
<div class="DropdownWidget---dropdown_value" id="3a5fa336ce7939555b5cd5d4fcb714fa_value" role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-controls="3a5fa336ce7939555b5cd5d4fcb714fa_list" aria-expanded="false" aria-activedescendant="" aria-labelledby="3a5fa336ce7939555b5cd5d4fcb714fa" aria-describedby="3a5fa336ce7939555b5cd5d4fcb714fa_selectedChoice">

<!-- react-text: 15 -->Element1<!-- /react-text -->

<span id="3a5fa336ce7939555b5cd5d4fcb714fa_selectedChoice" class="DropdownWidget---accessibilityhidden">element1</span>

</div>
```

The list in drop down gets generated in the HTML when we click it. Xpath is unable to detect it.

Please help..

Comment: Please show more HTML code,  seems the current HTML code not include any HTML of submenus

Comment: There is no submenus..when I click on element 2, this piece of code changes to Element 2 code

Comment: Show the HTML code when you cick on it, the dropdown menu will display. Show the HTML code of dropdown menu, tell us which menu you want to choose

Answer (score 0):

The best pattern is to convince a developer to add `data-test-id="MyDropdownWidget"` to DOM element that you want to test like:

```
<div data-test-id="MyDropdownWidget" ...
```

Then you can access it via `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//@*[starts-with('MyDropdownWidget','data-test-id')...`

Comment: Is there any other possible way?

Comment: Hard to say something more based on your example, you can use css classes or whatever than you can trigger click actions (then dropdown content should render). If you can put more rendered content around the element that you want to test.